# JQuery Failed to Handle Button's On Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know this question may be stupid, but I'm new to JQuery and failed to guess (even after hard search at Google) Why My Function failed to Show me Alert on Click Event of Button, (I'm trying to do more tasks but for debugging purpose I'm showing alert).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebSite Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#foo').click(function(){
            alert('ggg');
        });
    });
</script>
 </head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Get Data" id="foo">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move script to another script tag

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#foo').click(function(){
            alert('ggg');
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan that should be posted in answer and accepted by the OP so it can be removed from the list of open questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Totally Agreed with Answers of above two users, You have to Put Your Code away from the tags referencing the Libraries, What you need to do is place your logical code may be of Javascript or JQuery in Another Script Tags

Comment: So, figure out who first answered correctly, and mark *their* answer correct. No your own, copied answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Pranav mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072616/jquery-failed-to-handle-buttons-on-click-event#comment69351938_41072616), you should separate the scripts, so each can work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquer‌​y.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
      alert('ggg');
    });
  });
</script>
```